# UIViewControllerRepresentable doesn't update currently only in iOS 14

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I created UIViewControllerRepresentable to present popover.

I did test it on Xcode 13 and iOS 15 it working great as video on this [link](https://a.cl.ly/bLud6beD)

But it doesn't work as expected on Xcode 12.5.1 and iOS 14.8 as video on this [link](https://a.cl.ly/2NuP185D)

I don't know why it doesn't work on iOS 14.8 , is there other solution to make it work on both iOS versions ?

**My code :**

```
struct PopoverViewModifier<PopoverContent>: ViewModifier where PopoverContent: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    let content: () -> PopoverContent

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                Popover(
                    isPresented: self.$isPresented,
                    onDismiss: self.onDismiss,
                    content: self.content
                )
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func cocoaPopover<Content>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil,
        content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) -> some View where Content: View {
        ModifiedContent(
            content: self,
            modifier: PopoverViewModifier(
                isPresented: isPresented,
                onDismiss: onDismiss,
                content: content
            )
        )
    }
}

struct Popover<Content: View> : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self, content: self.content())
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
        
        let host = context.coordinator.host
        host.rootView = content()
        
        if host.viewIfLoaded?.window == nil && self.isPresented {
            host.preferredContentSize = host.sizeThatFits(in: CGSize(width: Int.max , height: Int.max))
            host.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
            host.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
            host.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = uiViewController.view
            host.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = uiViewController.view.bounds
            
            uiViewController.present(host, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if self.isPresented == false {
            host.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
        let host: UIHostingController<Content>
        private let parent: Popover

        init(parent: Popover, content: Content) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.host = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        }

        func presentationControllerWillDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            self.parent.isPresented = false
            if let onDismiss = self.parent.onDismiss {
                onDismiss()
            }
        }

        func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
            return .none
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with the Representable. It seems there may be a bug in iOS14 and the way it handles buttons on a Toolbar. When you place a button inside a Toolbar, its geometry behavior is a little strange (on iOS14). Run the following code and check the results on both iOS versions.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("Show") {
                    show = true
                }
                .border(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On iOS 15, it will look like this:

[image]

but on iOS 14, it looks like this:

[image]

So what happened to the green border? Anything placed in a border, overlay or background gets drawn somewhere else (and for what I've seen so far, out of the screen).

*Note that this problem only occurs for buttons ***inside*** a toolbar.*

This bad geometry has a direct effect on your popover. So if we find a way to fix that geometry, the problem for your popover will go away too. I can think of two workarounds:

1. Replace your button with a tappable text:

```swift
Text("Show").onTapGesture { ... }
```

This works, but if you want to emulate the look of a real button, you'll need to put some more work. Fortunately, there's workaround number 2.

2. Use a transparent Text as your toolbar item, and place the button over it:

```swift
struct ContentViewx: View {
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Text("Show")
                    .opacity(0)
                    .overlay(
                        Button("Show") {
                            show = true
                        }
                    )
                    .cocoaPopover(isPresented: $show) {
                        print("dismiss!")
                    } content: {
                        Text("Hello, this is the popover!")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to change it back to Button only , and replace toolBar to .navigationBarItems(trailing:) , it working without any issue in both versions

Comment: Even better. Good to know!